# How to call many functions in one main function oracle pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have 6 small functions and want to call all 6 functions in one main function

Like in Main function want to call 6 functions:

```
v_CASE_A := FUNCTION_1

v_CASE_B := FUNCTION_2
```

And so on.

Example This is small function_1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION u_t (v_number IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    v_length   NUMBER;
    result     VARCHAR2 (100);
    v_figure   VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
    v_length := LENGTH (v_number);
    v_figure := TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (v_number, 'J'), 'JSP');

    IF v_length IN (1, 2)
    THEN
        --**result := i want to call v_case_a in this variable from main function;**
    END IF;

    RETURN RESULT;
END;
```

Example This is main function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION number_to_words (v_number IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    v_result   VARCHAR2 (500);
    v_figure   VARCHAR2 (100);
    v_case_A   VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
    v_result := v_case_A;
    v_figure := TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (v_number, 'J'), 'JSP');

    --**v_case_A := i want to call function_1 in this variable;**

    RETURN v_result;
END;
```

How to call multiple functions in one main function PL/SQL?

Comment: CASE STATEMENT or one by one. Please show your code

Comment: v_case_a is a variable like v_case_a := function_1

Comment: You can assign values to as many variables as you want. If you could post an example of what you are trying to do, that would help a lot.

Comment: @William Robertson i edited my question please look 2 examples and want result in double star highlight

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"call function_1 in this variable"*, or *"call v_case_a in this variable from main function"*. Do you want to set a variable to the result of a function? What's wrong with `var := fun();`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but it sounds like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION number_to_words (v_number IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    v_result   VARCHAR2 (500);
BEGIN
    -- classical if-block
    IF v_number = 1
    THEN
        v_result := function1 ();
    ELSIF v_number = 2
    THEN
        v_result := function2 ();
    ELSE
        v_result := functionDefaultBehaviour ();
    END IF;

    -- case-block
    CASE v_number
    WHEN 1 THEN
        v_result := function1 ();
    WHEN 2 THEN
        v_result := function2 ();
    ELSE
        v_result := functionDefaultBehaviour ();
    END CASE;

    RETURN v_result;
END;
```

`v_result` is set to the return-values of `function1`, `function2` and `functionDefaultBehaviour` depending on the parameter `v_number`.

This is run two times - by a if-else-block and a second time with the more beautifil case-statements.